# Create and show View in a WizardPage

Tags: eclipse, plugins, view, perspective

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin. It creates a button in the Eclipse toolbar that launches a wizard. I need to add a view e.g. *Package Explorer* view, on a specific `WizardPage`.

How can I do this?

UPDATE:

Work with this:

```java
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel; 
...
checkboxTreeViewer.setContentProvider(new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());
checkboxTreeViewer.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
treeViewer.setInput(CoreModel.create(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()))
```

But it show both project's `src` directory and `Debug` directory. How can I show only `src` directory?

Comment: Is this just to select files in the wizard or do you need more than that?

Comment: I need to show package explorer in order to select files (source code) in a specific project and/or also specific function in a source code file; based on these selections i'll make some operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show a view (anything derived from `ViewPart`) in a wizard because it relies on the view infrastructure provided by Eclipse that is not available in a wizard.

You can create a `TreeViewer` and populate it with the files and folders in the workspace. The content provider, label provider and input would be something like this:

```
   treeViewer.setContentProvider(new WorkbenchContentProvider());
   treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
   treeViewer.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace());
```

Comment: Thanks! otherwise if i wanna use View i have to develop an RCP application, right?

Comment: If you mean a view in a wizard, yes, you would have to develop an RCP. Even then it would be very hard to use the existing package explorer view.

Comment: Using this solution i view only folders and file. I need to see also method/function defined in that files. How can i do this?

Comment: Never tried this but it looks like you can do something with `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaElementLabelProvider` and `StandardJavaElementContentProvider`.

Comment: Unfortunately don't work. i try this:

treeViewer.setContentProvider(new StandardJavaElementContentProvider());
  treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
  treeViewer.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace());

Comment: Looks like need `setInput(JavaCore.create(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot())`

Comment: I edit like this and seems work:
treeViewer.setContentProvider(new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new WorkbenchLabelProvider());
treeViewer.setInput(JavaCore.create(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()));

But i need to view also C/C++ project. Solutions?